Bypass pipeline setting enabled at organizational level in Azure DevOps
In my Azure DevOps organization I enabled "Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines" and for release pipelines.
Within my organization I have a project where a certain pipeline needs to access a feed from a different project. I want to allow this.
I tried to connect the aff ected pipeline to the target project using a npm service connection and a PAT but it did not work.
Is there a workaround that can I use, or will the Organizational level Setting block any kind of attempt or workaround?
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '18.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- task: npmAuthenticate@0
  inputs:
    workingFile: 'my_configuration_file_for_node_package_manager'
    customEndpoint: 'Name_of_my_service_connection'  

- script: |
    # Fail this step if any of the scripts fail
    set -e
    # Run npm scripts
    npm install
    npm run lint
    npm run test:ci
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install, lint, test and build'


Workaround:
so I created 2 projects (source project and target project).
I get the following error.
2024-06-06T13:35:21.1839639Z ##[section]Starting: npmAuthenticate
2024-06-06T13:35:21.1844933Z ==============================================================================
2024-06-06T13:35:21.1845088Z Task         : npm authenticate (for task runners)
2024-06-06T13:35:21.1845208Z Description  : Don't use this task if you're also using the npm task. Provides npm credentials to an .npmrc file in your repository for the scope of the build. This enables npm task runners like gulp and Grunt to authenticate with private registries.
2024-06-06T13:35:21.1845491Z Version      : 0.238.2
2024-06-06T13:35:21.1845563Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2024-06-06T13:35:21.1845650Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm-authenticate
2024-06-06T13:35:21.1845803Z ==============================================================================
2024-06-06T13:35:21.7016864Z ##[error]Error: The .npmrc file you selected at /home/vsts/work/1/s/source-repo/.npmrc does not currently exist.
2024-06-06T13:35:21.7053999Z ##[section]Finishing: npmAuthenticate
I attached the screenshot with a my nmprc file


I can reproduce the same situation. When the option: Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines is enabled, the access to the feed from another project will be limited.

Is there a workaround that can I use, or will the Organizational level Setting block any kind of attempt or workaround?

To workaround this issue, you can add the .npmrc file to the same path as Package.json file.
For example:

Then you can add the following content in the .npmrc file
; begin auth token
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/<ORGANIZATION_NAME>/<Project_NAME>/_packaging/<FEED_NAME>/npm/registry/:username=[ENTER_ANY_VALUE_BUT_NOT_AN_EMPTY_STRING]
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/<ORGANIZATION_NAME>/<Project_NAME>/_packaging/<FEED_NAME>/npm/registry/:_password=[BASE64_ENCODED_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN]
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/<ORGANIZATION_NAME>/<Project_NAME>/_packaging/<FEED_NAME>/npm/registry/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn't use the value
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/<ORGANIZATION_NAME>/<Project_NAME>/_packaging/<FEED_NAME>/npm/:username=[ANY_VALUE_BUT_NOT_AN_EMPTY_STRING]
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/<ORGANIZATION_NAME>/<Project_NAME>/_packaging/<FEED_NAME>/npm/:_password=[BASE64_ENCODED_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN]
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/<ORGANIZATION_NAME>/<Project_NAME>/_packaging/<FEED_NAME>/npm/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn't use the value
; end auth token

Note: You need to convert the PAT to Base64 format and add to the .npmrc file.
In Azure DevOps Pipeline, you can remove the npmAuthenticate task.
For example:
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '18.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'
 

- script: |
    # Fail this step if any of the scripts fail
    set -e
    # Run npm scripts
    npm install
    npm run lint
    npm run test:ci
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install, lint, test and build'

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Connect to Feed
Update:
To use npm service connection and  npmAuthenticate task to authenticate the feed resource in another project.
You can use the following sample:
1.Add an .npmrc file to your project and add the following content：
registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<ORGANIZATION_NAME>/<PROJECT_NAME>/_packaging/<FEED_NAME>/npm/registry/ 

always-auth=true

2.In Azure Pipeline, you need to add the argument: --userconfig xxx/.npmrc to force the Npm task to use the target .npmrc file.
Here is an example:
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '18.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- task: npmAuthenticate@0
  inputs:
    workingFile: 'your .npmrc file'
    customEndpoint: 'Name_of_my_service_connection'  

- script: |
 
    set -e
    # Run npm scripts
    npm install --userconfig Path/.npmrc
    npm run lint
    npm run test:ci
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install, lint, test and build'


I tried to connect the aff ected pipeline to the target project using a npm service connection and a PAT but it did not work.

The cause of the issue is the Pipeline contains two .npmrc files. One is Project level (Use PAT) and the other is User level(Use Service account). By default, it will use User Level .npmrc file. So it will have no access to feed from another project due to limitation

Thank you for your reply! If I add the Upstream source in the current project feed do I also need to ensure that the pipeline is using a service connection or a PAT that has the necessary permissions. ?

@MyADOObsession If you use upstream source in current project feed, it can by pass the limitation of the pipeline. If you use PAT or service connection, you need to make sure that the account has the access to the current and another project feed.

I still get the same Error after adding the feed to the affected project npm error 404 Not Found - GET https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/mycompany//_packaging/myproject/npm/registry/@my-company/utilities/-/utilities-0.3.2.tgz -: The project with id 'vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/' does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it.

@MyADOObsession can you try to use the .npmrc file method and check if it can work？

what if I create the same feed with organization scope? I guess this should solve it also, right?

@MyADOObsession No. The issue will still exist. The limitation of the pipeline will force the pipeline to only access the feed from current project. The Organization Scope feed is outside project feed. I suggest that you can try to use the npmrc file to workaround the issue.

@MyADOObsession Refer to my update in the answer, You can use the argument: --userconfig  in Npm install step. And it can help you use the PAT to authenticate the feed from another project and by pass the limitation. It will work for using feed from another project directly or use upstream source.

ok, so following the 2 steps from the Update should solve it?

@MyADOObsession Yes. The steps in the update will solve the issue.

I will try it today on my own test environment and let you know, thank you for your support

I updated the main thread, with the workaround, I am not sure why I can not run the  npm adduser --registry properly

@MyADOObsession I suggest that you can use the workaround in the update content of the answer. It will be more safe. Can you try it?

You don’t need to directly input the base64 pat to the .npmrc file

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@MyADOObsession The correct path: $(build.sourcesdirectory)/.npmrc you can try this path

@MyADOObsession For your last question, I have added the comment in the  chatroom.  You can check it.
